# When cloning a large django project, to set up the local database is it recommended to run all of the migrations since forever, or start fresh?

Tags: django, django-models

I just cloned a large django project and if I run the migrations I get errors. I wanted to know if it's necessary to go into each migration file and fix it, or to somehow skip them. I know in rails that in a situation like this one is advised to load the schema instead of running all of the past migrations, and wondered if it was the same for django. I know that one option is to delete all of the migrations, but since I am on a team that already has their local databases set up, I cant commit a deletion of all the migrations for my whole team, just so I can migrate my local database. How do I migrate my new local database given there are tons of migrations with tons of bugs and I mustn't delete the migration files for my git repo?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Something would have had to go really wrong for that to happen. Another options is [squashing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) which will let you reduce the migrations to a single one, but keep the old ones until they can be safely deleted.

Comment: Take a look at squashing migrations in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations